# Python sort by simple enum-like feld

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, enums

I want to let a user manipulate a (not really big, ~800 data rows) data collection, and let them apply filter/sorts like one would do on Excel.

I am reading data from a csv, with the following structure

```
Program | Mesh | Degree | Proc | Min | Max | Average | Status
-------------------------------------------------------------
'prog1' | 4x4x4| 2x2x2  | 2x1x1| 3.52| 3.8 | 3.72    | 'ok'
'prog2' | 8x4x4| 2x2x2  | 2x2x1| 3.60| 3.9 | 3.80    | 'Warning...'
```

Suppose I have already filtered my list how and I need to sort by 'Proc', how would I do that ? The proc column is actually a "string" of enum-like values

```
'1x1x1' < '2x1x1' < '2x2x1' < ... < '64x64x64' (powers of 2)
```

There are not so many "enum" values, but I still don't feel like having a switch... I thought maybe I could actually convert them to integer (by executing the multiplication), but then I lose the "label" (In my graphs I'd want to display that "axbxc")

My top goal is to define a top level function "sort_data" where one can provide as argument an arbitrary number of column headers, and the program should sort accordingly

eg.

```
sort_data('proc') # => Sort data per Proc column (axbxc values)
sort_data('proc', 'mesh') # => Sort data per proc and then by mesh (axbxc)
```

Since the dataset isn't that big and for non-real time computation, I'm more in favor of readable solutions than efficient (performance wise)

EDIT : for filtering I have something like that

```
def filter_program:
  self.filtered = [sample for sample in self.data_pointer if sample.program == program]

# similar for all columns, except the `if` clause gets more complicated
# (I have the code, no problem on those ones)

def filter(self, filter_dict):
    """Execute several filters."""
    for header, value in filter_dict.iteritems():
        if header in self.headers():
            getattr(self, 'filter_'+header)(value)
            self.active_filters[header] = value
        else:
            print('ERROR : unknown filter ' + column + ' (previous filters applied)')
    return self.filtered
```

Writing the filter method was easy since we can apply filters one after another. For sorting it's a bit more complicated since we want to passe a tuple to the sort method (sort by tuple[0] then by tuple[1]...), and that those sort functions need to be able to sort the dimension '1x1x1', etc).

```
def sort(self, sort_dict):
  for header, value in sort_dict.iteritems():
    if !(header in self.headers()):
      # error
      return
  self.sorted = sorted(self.filtered, key=lambda row: (### ??? ###)
```

The code for the `key lambda` of sort must be a tuple that akes into account all sort criteria of sort_dict. If I wanted to sort by min/average, I'd do

```
# sort_order = ['min', 'max']
sorted(self.filtered, key=lambda row: (float(row.min), float(row.max))
```

An example use would be :

```
sort_order([
  'mesh' # 1x1x1 then 2x1x1 then 2x2x1 ...
  'program' # 'alphabetical': prog1 then prog2 ...
})
```

Comment: I think the question would profit from some best try of that top level function ;-) also I'd suggest, to not multiply, but instead split on the character `x` of the strings into integer tuples like `proc_triplet = tuple(int(z) for z in proc_string.split('x'))` for the ordering checks, as this to me looks like a canonical well-behaved transformation in your case and allows for easy "display" reverts like: `proc_display = 'x'.join(proc_triplet)` or the like.

Comment: `TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, tuple found`. I will edit my question with more stuff